# Scoring and ranking specificity rules

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have two competing rules in my stylesheet:

```css
#parent > div {
    color: blue;
}

#child {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```html
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">What color is this text?</div>
 <div>This should just be blue</div>
 <div>Also should be blue</div>
</div>
```

**Why is `#child` blue and not red?**

I'm not sure if I'm applying the scoring system correctly.  Here's how I did it:

- rule #1 has an id and a tag, so its score is `[0, 1, 0, 1]`
- rule #2 has only an id, so its score is `[0, 1, 0, 0]`
- therefore rule #1 wins, and it's blue

But this *seems* wrong to me -- the first rule matches multiple elements; the second rule can only match one!  So isn't the second rule more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this *seems* wrong to me -- the first rule matches multiple elements; the second rule can only match one! So isn't the second rule more specific?

Not at all. Just because a selector matches fewer elements doesn't make it more specific.

Selector matching is done on a by-element basis, not a by-rule basis. Since there's a more specific selector that matches your element `#child`, which is `#parent > div`, that rule takes precedence, and that's it.

It does seem counter-intuitive, but that's just how it works. One way around this is to add `#parent` to your second rule:

```css
#parent > div {
    color: blue;
}

#parent > #child {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: You could also think of it this way: rule #1 applies to `div` elements only if they are children of any element with the ID `#parent`, while rule #2 simply applies to any element with the ID `#child`, wherever it is in the HTML. Notice how this makes rule #2 less specific? Remember that CSS itself doesn't  know about the actual HTML it's being applied to, hence my remark about how the number of elements matched *doesn't* influence specificity.

Comment: I see your point, but the id's are supposed to be unique, so `any element with id <x>` is *supposed* to never match more than one element.  That's why I think it's non-intuitive.

Comment: Indeed. However, the rule about IDs being unique is normative only to HTML, and as it turns out, CSS doesn't enforce the rule. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329/106224) for details.