# CSS selectors denormalized

Tags: html, css-selectors

There is a written (several times) rule that sais that **an *#id* selector identifies an unique element into a DOM tree**.

This is always followed by the conclusion that **only one alone element with this *#id* can exist into the DOM tree**.

So if you need to use a CSS selector for a kind of element that has another occurrences into the DOM tree you have to use a *.class* selector.

Well, I have serios doubts about this constriction also I think is not responding to a real need and avoiding a more intuitive use of the *#id* and *.class* selectors.

The question:

Existing the [chain selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) like *'#id1 #id2'* I could understand that *#id2* better to be unique into the *#id1* context, but **which is the meaning of forcing that *#id2* should be unique into the whole DOM context?**

This rule is just fueling a degenerative hell of *id* nonsense-naming. Also forcing us to over use the *class* attribute.

I feel more confortable avoiding this rule and building structures like this, *(please understand that the code is simplified and not using concrete HTML structures in propose)*:

```
<div id="armys" class="list">
  <div id="1" class="element">
    <div id="orders" class="text">My orders</div>
    <div id="soldiers" class="list">
      <div id="1" class="element">
        <div id="name" class="text">John</div>
      </div>
      <div id="2" class="element">
        <div id="name" class="text">Esther</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>

  <div id="2" class="element">
    <div id="orders" class="text">My orders</div>
    <div id="soldiers" class="list">
      <div id="3" class="element">
        <div id="name" class="text">Smith</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Which is a very much natural translation of an structure like this:

```
armys: [
  {
    id: 1,
    orders: "My orders",
    soldiers: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Esther"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    orders: "My orders",
    soldiers: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Smith"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This isn't a question so much as a rant. To have valid HTML, you need to use unique identifiers. That's the way it was defined.

Comment: It's not a restriction. It's just axiom. What do you mean with "overuse" of class attribute? Do you know that one element can have multiple classes (space-separated in value of `class` attribute) at the same time?

Comment: @zzzzBov the question is: _which is the meaning of forcing that #id2 should be unique into the whole DOM context?_

Comment: @MaratTanalin as I can't have multiple _id="soldiers"_ in the same page I have to move this classification to the _class_ attribute, when for me it is a clear unique element for the "#armys #1" element and not a "kind of..." as I see the _class_ attribute.

Comment: @fguillen, you should read the [HTML spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute), because it seems you don't understand the underlying rules.

Comment: Your `soldiers` elements are a class of element, a number of elements containing soldiers. `<div id="d23" class="soldiers list">` (using an arbitrary unique `id` to denote a particular army's soldiers)

Comment: @fguillen: Talking this way, each element is unique, and classes are unneeded at all which is not truth. You not can't. You just shouldn't.

Comment: @zzzzBov you are very right I just realized that what is exactly saying is _"The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree"_ and what I understand with [home subtree](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/infrastructure.html#home-subtree) is the context of the first ancestor of the element. So I think I was confused, and I think I wasn't the unique, and what the rule really is is: **"An ID has to be unique in amongst all the elements with the same parent"**. If this is true is gonna be a shutdown discussions.

Comment: you know, when i was first learning html, css etc, using the validator really helped me understand what you can and can't do.  because the HTML spec is one thing, but each browser implements things a little differently. validate your pages here: http://validator.w3.org/ and see what the w3c tells you about it.

Comment: I can't figure out how best to edit your question other than by removing more than half of it, which I imagine isn't something you'd like me to do. You're in a better position to work out a more straightforward and less confusing/ranty/rhetorical way to put forth your question.

Comment: FWIW, CSS does not care that an ID in an HTML document (or any other document) is unique. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329/106224) and [the comment thread under this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't approaching this correctly. The class and ID attributes aren't meant for CSS, nor for JavaScript. They are meant to IDentify and CLASSify the different elements.

Unique elements get an ID, that has merits in CSS and JavaScript, as well as native browser behavior (Jump to the ID if the matching anchor link is clicked).

Elements similar in meaning get a shared class name. This helps classify them in CSS and JavaScript (HELPS!), to have a better grouping of similar elements.

Also, FYI, there are different elements that represent unordered lists and list items, so that you won't have a page filled in unnecessary divs.

Comment: I have not talked about CSS but CSS selectors **.** Anchor links match with 'name' not 'id' **.** I don't see the constraint of 'whole DOM id uniqueness' a help for classify, especially having the 'chain selectors' **.** I already have said that 'I am simplifying my example in propose'

Comment: @fguillen, fragment identifier links (i.e. `<a href="#foo">foo</a>`) are defined as going to the element with a particular `[id]` in the [HTML spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#scroll-to-fragid)

Comment: @zzzzBov you are right I misunderstood the specifications with this [W3 org about anchor](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) _"the attribute NAME allows the anchor to be the destination of a link"_

Comment: @fguillen, that's an archive from 1995...Much has changed since then.