# difference between using MULTIPLE 'id' and 'class' attributes in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors, dom-traversal

According to CSS principles when we want to implement reusability of styles we should use `class` attribute and when we know that there is an unique element in whole DOM structure we should use `id` attribute to that Element and then specify a style.

But in this era of Web Applications, DOM structure can be too complex and there is a possibility of duplicate `id`. Best example would be `#title`. Its kind of name which can appear anywhere in the document. Now the best part is if I use `#title` or `.title` while defining styles (assuming that they have been appeared more than once and have different parent) output which CSS generates is same. This jsfiddle will help you understand what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/dewbot/LGAQD/

I was under impression that just like JS Renderer, CSS Parser halts the iteration when it discovers first `#title` but it does not happen it keeps on iteration till it reaches EOF just like `class`. So this arises a question why should we use multiple `class` and not `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So this arises a question why should we use multiple `class` and not `id`?

[Because the HTML spec says so](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), and breaking the rules often results in broken code.

Does it make sense to *identify* multiple elements by the same ID? I think not. That's what classes are for: to *classify* similar elements.

> Now the best part is if I use `#title` or `.title` while defining styles (assuming that they have been appeared more than once and have different parent) output which CSS generates is same.

This is natural behavior, and not a bug in any browsers that do this *per se*. Still, it is not the kind of behavior that you should rely on as it deals with non-conformant markup, which is usually bad.

> I was under impression that just like JS Renderer, CSS Parser halts the iteration when it discovers first `#title` but it does not happen it keeps on iteration till it reaches EOF just like `class`.

Now this is wrong. CSS parsers do selector matching *on a per-element basis*: they don't take a rule and walk through the DOM applying it to whatever elements match it; instead, they take each element and attempt to match it against as many rules as possible. Working this way, a parser *doesn't know* whether an ID is already in use elsewhere in the document, nor does it care. It simply matches *according to what the element says it is*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813672/106224) covers it in greater detail.

As long as an element has a certain ID, it must match against any ID selectors looking for that specific ID. So, parsers are expected to match any and all elements with a given ID to a single ID selector, even though in HTML it's not correct to have multiple elements with the same ID. In other words, CSS does not enforce the uniqueness of IDs that is required of HTML. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329/106224) explains.

With all that said, the bottom line is: **assign an ID to only one element at a time**, and use classes for grouping multiple similar elements. **Don't try to be clever and bend the rules.**

Comment: _Does it make sense to identify multiple elements by the same ID_ as I said Complex DOM Structure. If job of an element is to act as title then it will have `id` as "title". But the naming convention which @Anubhav specified here is what I actually wanted. 

Anyways those links are good reads. Big Help! Thanks

Comment: @dewbot: It doesn't matter how complex it is or what naming conventions you use. It's still a single DOM structure, and **the rules say an ID must only appear once in a single document at a time**. That's what I'm driving at.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the parsing of the CSS wrong. The browser doesn't go through the CSS file line for line and applies the styles to the elements in the HTML file, it is the other way around. The browser parses the HTML and whenever it finds a `class` or `id` attribute, it looks it up in the CSS files. (This is very simplified, but it helps to get the point).

Just because the browser renders it correctly if you have multiple `id`s doesn't mean you should do it. The [standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html) [clearly says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) that the `id` **has** to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered it yourself.

CSS does apply it to all of the `id`s and `class`es it can find. But, JS/ jQuery will implement it to the first it finds.

So, your question becomes:

Should I apply same `id`s to many elements for JS manipulation? Answer: **Baaaaa....D decision**

Should I apply same `id`'s to many elements for CSS? Answer: **still bad, decision! but will implement that rules of yours**

You should also try to use CSS and JS rules applied in hierarchical way, that way, you can never go wrong. Like, `#Heading div#Title{css rules here}` or `$('#Heading div#Titles')...jQuery rules here`

Next thing is try to implement ids in a conservative way.

Then, try to provide unique id for element in your website/app rather than single page. This will save you from multi-page utility Scripts you include in your pages.

for example: Heading on the top of the Home page: `#Home-Top-Heading`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> your code will not pass validation if you use the same ID on more
>   than one

CSS dont care about mutliple id's , javascript cares

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/