# CSS Selectors performance, DOM Parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

My question is related to DOM parsing getting triggered, i would like to know why it's faster to use a CSS ID selector than a Class selector. When does the DOM tree have to be parsed again, and what tricks and performance enhancements should I use... also, someone told me that if I do something like

```
var $p = $("p");  
$p.css("color", "blue"); 
$p.text("Text changed!");
```

instead of

```
$("p").css("color", "blue");  
$("p").text("Text changed!");
```

improves performance, is this true for all browsers? Also how do I know if my DOM tree has been re-parsed?

Comment: CSS selector parsing performance alone is microscopic enough. Throwing jQuery's different ways of interpreting different selectors (CSS or non-CSS) into the mix just makes everything unnecessarily confusing. It's not worth agnonizing over these nuances.

Comment: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/ lists many rules for jquery perf improvement

Comment: Also note that you can method chain. So you can do `$('p').css('').text('').morestuff()` to improve performance too

Comment: yep, my only caveat with chaining is that sometimes you get lost in the chain, also harder to debug, unless there is a trick for doing it differently? I guess i will have to get used to it, it's the jQuery way of doing many things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, an `#id` selector is faster than class selectors because: (a) there can only be one element with a given id value; (b) browsers can hold a map `id -> element`, so the `#id` selector can work as quick as a single map lookup.

Next, the first option suggested above is definitely faster, as it avoids the second lookup, thereby reducing the total selector-based lookup time by a factor of 2.

Last, you can use Chrome Developer Tools' **Selector Profiler** (in the **Profiles** panel) to profile the time it takes a browser to process selectors in your page (match + apply styles to the matching elements.)

Comment: Hey, didn't know about Selector Profiler. Thanks! +1 for me.

Comment: Only a JavaScript selector library would treat a CSS ID selector as a `getElementById()` call, and retrieve the first element with the matching ID. Strictly speaking, a conforming CSS selector engine needs to match *all* elements with a given ID to that ID selector, even if there is more than one, so if a browser holds such a map, it won't be relevant to this particular matching procedure. But granted we're talking about jQuery here...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I know you are fond of specs :), so [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id) says that the `id` attribute value must be **unique** in a document. The browser behavior in the case of several elements having the same `id` value is undefined otherwise (definitely more so, if `document.getElementById()` is used.)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: That's HTML, not CSS, which explains why DOM implementation use `document.getElementById()`. Good call, though.

Comment: Apologies for the wrong reference. [The CSS2 spec ID Selectors chapter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) says that "whatever the document language, an ID attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element."

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov: According to the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why), that's informative, and has no impact on the effect of CSS ID selectors on a document. Also see [my recent answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329/106224). I'm probably making unnecessary comments here, though, as like I mentioned we're talking jQuery/JS here. Just some extra info, though!

Comment: Hmm... Looking at the spec, I didn't find any sign of the quote above being informative. [Moreover](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors), "An ID selector represents an element instance that has an identifier that matches the identifier in the ID selector." Supposedly, _a single instance_.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Very helpful! I feel like a total newb in JS/JQuery, well I am :) I have found that there are a lot of tricks one has to pay attention to.

Comment: On a side note, WebKit _does_ support ID selector matching for multiple elements with the same ID. I will clarify this with the author of the CSS package once he's available, but presumably, this is to avoid artifacts in broken documents (having multiple elements with the same ID).

Comment: @AdamSurfari: you don't have to, most of the time. As the current author/maintainer of the CSS package in WebKit said (close to the original text), "If a selector is slow, we should optimize WebKit" [rather than a web developer should optimize his selectors].

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to make your own performance tests whenever you have a doubt. You can get more info on how to do that here: [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code). Once you've tested performance on your own, you'll never forget the results.

In particular, the execution of the `$()` function on a given jquery selector must obtain the matching DOM nodes. I'm not sure exactly how this works but I'm guessing it is a combination of `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByTagName()` and others. This has a processing cost, no matter how small it may be, if you call it only once and then reuse it you save some processing time.

Answer (score 1):

An ID selector is faster than a class selector because there is only one element with an ID but many elements could share a class and they have to be searched.

The code below is needlessly parsing the DOM twice, so of course it will be slower:

```
$("p").css("color", "blue");  
$("p").text("Text changed!");
```