# How do I close the tab? (Octobercms Component, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, twig, octobercms

htm

```
<div id="tab" name="{{__SELF__.id}}" class="my-tab">
    <img id="tab-avatar" style="height:50px; width:50px" src="{{__SELF__.avatarImage}}">
    <div id="tab-minimize">
        <div id="tab-label"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand" name="{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close" name="{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-close tab-btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".tab-close").each(function(){
        var tabName = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).click(function(){ 
            $(".my-tab").each(function(){
                $("tabName").addClass("hidden");
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Now I have two tabs(tabs which are duplicated), both have the same class name, id, etc. The only diff is they have their own unique name.

How to close the tab when I press the close button of the specific tab?

Meaning I want to click tab 1 close button to close tab 1 and click tab 2 close button to close tab 2.

Answer (score 0):

> both have the same class name, id, etc

`class` can be same but `id` must be unique.

```
$(function(){
    $(".tab-btn").on('click',function(event){
        $(this).closest('.my-tab').addClass('hidden')
  })
});
```

Comment: but the tabs are duplicated that's why they will have the same id but they have a unqiue id which I set it to the name. which means          component 1          <div id="tab" name="uniqueID_1" class="my-tab">
    <img id="tab-avatar" style="height:50px; width:50px" src="{{__SELF__.avatarImage}}">
    <div id="tab-minimize">
        <div id="tab-label"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand" name="uniqueID_1" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close" name="uniqueI_D1" class="tab-close tab-btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>                     and component 2 name="uniqueID_2"

Comment: what ever it is id can never be duplicate, name can be duplicate since name represent same set of element.Check mozilla development network and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079756/using-same-id-for-in-multiple-html-tags)

Comment: hmm... Do you know about octobercms component and twig? cause actually I was told to use twig to set the unique ID for each duplicated component but I only know I need to put this in the htm {% set uid = '{{__SELF__.id}}' %} and I'm not very sure how to use it.

Comment: for all the duplicated components will be exactly the same the only diff is they have a unique id which is why put {{__SELF__.id}}, this helps to indicate their own unique id.