# Jquery: Selecting Siblings of $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jquery to see when an element is changed and then run an action that involves it sibling like this:

```
$('.row').find('#class').change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('#teacher').removeAttr('disabled');
        var class_id = $(this).val();
    });
```

so when the input with an id of `class` is changed it will get its value and then affect its sibling with an id of `teacher`.  They are both inside of `<div class="row">` and this is repeated several times on the page.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="grid_2">
        <select name="class" id="class">
        <option></option>
            //PHP that loads choices
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="grid_2">
            <select name="teacher" id="teacher" disabled="true">
                 //Ajax loads choices
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is repeated Several times through out the page.

What I need help with is how to select the 2nd select box when the first one (next to it) changes.

Thanks for the help.

edit: When i try to console.log `$(this).siblings()` it comes back with `[]` as a result.

Comment: Id's have to be *unique*

Comment: Is there a question in there, and what does the HTML look like ?

Comment: Aside from the comment made by @Andreas which is correct you didn't say what went wrong though I have a hunch.

Answer (score 5):

While you should **never** have multiple elements with the same ID, if you do, you could select them with an attribute selector:

```
$(this).siblings('[id=teacher]');
```

For more info, see: [Several elements with the same ID responding to one CSS ID selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector/7262229#7262229)