# Is there any performance advantage to using the E#C CSS selector over #C?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I'm currently reading up on jQuery to fill some gaps in knowledge.

Looking at the various CSS selectors, I see:-

- `#C` (any element with an ID of C)

  ```
  $('#profile')
  ```
- `E#C` (any element of type E with an ID of #C).

  ```
  $('div#profile')
  ```

I know specificity is a big deal in the application of CSS rules, but given that it is bad practice to have duplicate IDs on a page, I'm wondering why the second form exists and how it is treated in jQuery.

Does it confer a performance advantage when interrogating the DOM? ( i.e. immediately limiting the scope of the selection ).  This question applies mostly to jQuery, but I'd also be interested to know if it had any bearing on rendering engines, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a [specialized "fast path"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L127) to handle selectors of the form `#C` with a direct `document.getElementById`. Selectors of the form `E#C` are not handled by this path and are instead delegated to the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) library.

Therefore I don't see how `E#C` could offer any performance benefit in practice, while there's no argument for better performance in theory as well. Indeed, `E#C` is much slower; [see the massive performance difference here](http://jsperf.com/selecting-by-id-with-jquery)¹.

That said, the `E#C` selector is of course more restrictive so the *behavior* of the two will be different no matter if the selection is done by jQuery or any other medium. Even so I have never ever used `E#C` (or seen it used); I can't think of any reason to reuse an id across different pages.

---

¹Admittedly in real life that selector won't run in a loop, so the performance difference is not going to matter.

Comment: Jon, that is an excellent answer.  Unambiguous, backed up with paperwork and legwork.  Thanks.

Comment: Taken from my now-deleted answer: if you consider modern browsers and their CSS implementations, then as jQuery tries `document.querySelectorAll()` which uses a browser's native CSS selector engine, *before* falling back to Sizzle, this means using it with an ID selector will return all elements with that ID, and not just the first. In CSS, this applies to any ID selector and behaves the same with respect to any other selectors (e.g. attaching a type or class to the ID selector). Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses a bottom up search.  It starts at the last selector and filters up.

Example:

$('#id1 .class1 .class2')  looks for all classes of class2, then filters that result for all classes with a parent of class1 and then filters that further with a parent with id of id1

$('#profile') and $('div#profile') are essentially the same, roughly fractions of ms.  But it's good to know the performance benefits and how to appropriately traverse the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  Jon nailed the specifics, but I appreciate the additional context your answer provided.