# two identical div id's, modifying only one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So the code is like this:

```
<div id="logo"><img src="logourl"></div>
<div id="logo"><img src="logourl"></div>
```

I'm trying to `display: none` on the second one. Unfortunately, I am blocked from modifying the html, I am also unable to use js.  I'm stuck with CSS to try and fix this.

I thought maybe `#logo:last-child { display: none; }` might work, but since they're technically in different div's just have the same ID, I can't seem to get that working.  Any advice would be appreciated. I know the HTML is bad, but there's nothing I can do to fix that.  I've told my boss that several times already...

Comment: afair ID must be unique across dom

Comment: yep, in html 4.0 and xhtml `id` must be unique across document

Comment: The OP has said the HTML is bad, but has no control over it.

Comment: @Michael_B my point is that this is _not_ html according to standard, so even if some workaround will work - OP has argument for his boss

Comment: Well clearly OP's boss is having none of it, so what are you gonna do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#logo:last-child { display: none; }` should work, based on the code in your question.

But considering your HTML is invalid, you can try these alternatives:

```
div:last-child { display: none; }

div:last-child > img { display: none; }

div:last-of-type { display: none; }
```

You have mentioned that the HTML is bad and you have no control over it. But just for the record, each ID should be unique in the document. Having two ID's with identical values is not valid HTML.

Comment: There are no known instances of #logo:last-child not matching an [id=logo] that is not the first (or only) such element in the HTML document in any CSS implementation. The reasoning given by at least one implementer (I don't remember who, but I think it was Boris from Mozilla) is that CSS doesn't enforce document language constraints. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector/8753329#8753329). Still, the point remains...

Comment: Yep, I do know that each ID must be unique. 
So oddly enough #logo:last-child { display: none; } doesn't seem to do anything, likewise with #logo:last-child > img
However #logo:last-child img { display: none; } removes both of the images
#logo:last-of-type { display: none; } also removes both of them.  This site is freaking weird...

You can see the code working here. Scroll to the right a little bit and you'll see the logo banner appear twice:
https://jsfiddle.net/qodtvdL1/1/

Comment: Calling that HTML bad is very polite. (You're a good employee.) In reality, it's a bloody mess. The `nth-child` selectors won't help you in this case. Try this: `div#page_content #logo { display: none; }`

Comment: You are a wonderful human being, thank you.  That is perfect. :)

Answer (score -2):

An id must be a unique identifier.
Either use a class or multiple classes:

```
<div class="top" …
<div class="top left" …
```

The second example will match "top" and "left" classes.

Comment: Except OP has no control over the HTML and can't modify it.

Comment: As I said above, I do not have the ability to modify the HTML. I am well aware that the ID must be unique but it's not. I wish I could fix it, but I cannot.  My companies website is...well it was built by a monkey.