# Inner Divs overflow Outerdiv

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dynamically creating multiple divs inside a div. I want all these inner divs to avoid overflowing from the outer div. I have attached jsfiddle to reproduce the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/t3jgdodm/1/

attaching CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I want all divs to be under single scroll. 
I am using multiple divs as each div represents a new entered keyword and the div will dynamically generate inside the outer div. I am ready to change the div element into other HTML element if the problem if due to div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important note:** You're using repeating ID's which is completely taboo. Make them classes if you plan on re-using them, as I have in my example below.

To have a scrollbar on the outer div, put `overflow: auto` on your `#topDiv` instead of your `.insideDiv`. https://jsfiddle.net/t3jgdodm/11/

```
#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

I've added a `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#outerDiv` so that the `padding: 10px` + `width: 100%` doesn't cause it to flow off the screen.

Also, I've removed `max-height` from `.innerDiv` to avoid having them overlap.

Comment: You missed the middle div by the way, still has id="insideDiv" on it instead of class="insideDiv", no idea why this has been marked down though, first to answer and gave a good one at that.

Comment: @Santi Why does class and id behaves differently? I have never came across like this problem due to id and class naming.

Comment: Here's a good answer with a lot of information on why not to use repeating ID's: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8753329/2026606

Answer (score 2):

Is this what your trying to do?

https://jsfiddle.net/t3jgdodm/2/

```
#topDiv {
    background-color: lightblue;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

i added overflow-y: scroll to you #topDiv element id

Comment: I feel like it's important to note that OP is using the same ID for multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If I want these multiple divs to have a common scroll bar with that of the outer div scroll, then should I have to use some other element than div. If yes, which element will be prefered? @Snaterj

Comment: Divs are fine to use. It's that you can't have identical ID's. You need to use *classes*, as I've outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Santi updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t3jgdodm/12/     How to use only scroll bar of the outer div instead of each divs having their scroll bar.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha Again, please see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40551589/2026606). It includes all of these answers and a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `max-height: inherit` from the `#insideDiv` (it's inheriting the `max-height: 100px` from it's parent) and move the `overflow-y: auto` to the `#topDiv`.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

In your exact fiddle, the scrollbar gets pushed off the edge. That's just because the width of the `#topDiv` exceeds 100% (you need to add `box-sizing: content-box` to prevent that).

Also, probably just in your example, but remember you shouldn't have more than one element with any given ID. Use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have multiple `div`s with the same `id`, make that `id` a `class` first of all, secondly you have `max-height: inherit` on the `insidediv`, all this means is they get the `max-height` from the parent, so they'll have the same `max-height` as the `topDiv`, with no real restriction. The only real ways I can think of to fix this are to either put an `overflow: auto` on the outer div or somehow work out what the height of the `insidediv`s should be.

So to simplify, the HTML should be more like:

```
<div id="topDiv">
  <div class="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="insideDiv">
    <br>check
    <br>check
  </div>
  <div class="insideDiv">
    <br>check
    <br>check
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS should be more like:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or completely remove the overflow-y from the insideDiv class and keep it on just the topDiv id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with max height attribute. I changed the css to height.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 33%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give a proper answer for your issue.

---

Don't control overflow with the child (`#innerDiv`), control it with the parent (`#topDiv`). You don't tell water where to go, you put in a different-sized glass.

Here's an example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
      Some inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br> More inside content
      <br>
  </div>
</div>


#parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

remove "max-height: 100px" from topDiv. It will work