# Confused about descendant selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have the following selector:

```
#doctors h2 {
    /* CSS CODE HERE */
}
```

Is this selector pointing to all `<h2>` element that are descendants of elements with `id="doctor"`

Comment: Aside from the fact that it'd be `id="doctors"` and not `id="doctor"`, that seems fine. (Note that there should only be one element with an id of "doctors" though...it's an id.) Is there a particular difficulty you're having with this?

Comment: Yes, it is. please note that this includes _ANY_ `<h2>` within the `#doctors` element, even if they are a descendant of a descendant of a descendant of a ...

Comment: Yes that is the selector to modify all h2 elements contained in the doctors element.

Comment: It can't be elements with `#doctors` it can only be one element.

Comment: What would happen is there is more than one element with `id="doctors"` or is this not possible in HTML?

Comment: @VishwaIyer For that concern, consider reviewing [Several elements with the same ID responding to one CSS ID selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector). It works...in some use cases.

Comment: You should not use ids for CSS selectors at all. That's true even more so for selectors that have non-id selectors depend on id context (like in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. `#doctors h2` selects all `<h2>` elements which are descendants of the element with `id="doctors"`.