# What does quertySelector return null value?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

querySelector returns null when searched for the id "#b>a", but getElementById returns the correct element. What's going on?

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#b>a');
console.log(x);
var y = document.getElementById("b>a");
console.log(y);
```

```html
Name <input type="text" id="b>a">
```

Comment: Why do you need such name of an id because it is highly predicted to run in trouble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>` character has meaning in CSS selector syntax. You'd have to use `"#b\>a"`.

The `>` is the "immediate child" combinator, so plain `"#b>a"` selects an `<a>` element that's a child of your element with id "b".

Comment: ... at which point you might as well just use document.getElementById(), unless your use case requires a selector.

Comment: It's called a combinator ;)

Comment: @BoltClock agreed, though using selectors isn't weird or bad or anything, especially in the context of some sort of tooling/framework situation. *edit* yes dang it I was trying to remember the term; in my defense I was typing while on the phone ;)

Comment: Indeed, there are numerous situations that require a selector.

Comment: In [HTML 4 IDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) could not contain ">", dunno if it was ever enforced though (like IDs starting with a number were illegal but tolerated).

Comment: @RobG: It was never enforced. #b\>a will match elements with the corresponding id regardless of the doctype. This is precisely why they relaxed the restrictions in HTML5. ([The plural "elements" is not a typo, by the way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector/8753329#8753329))

Comment: [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) could be useful, since there are other characters as well that need to be escaped within CSS selectors. Mind the [browser compabitiliy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `>` character. See snippet below

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#b\\>a');
console.log(x);
var y = document.getElementById("b>a");
console.log(y);
```

```html
Name <input type="text" id="b>a">
```

Answer (score 1):

Query by selector will look for types before characters, so it will look for an  rather than the text a.

To get this to work you would need to escape the  selector using

```
var x = document.querySelector('#b\\>a');
```