# Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 1 elements that match locator By(xpath, //*[@id="testInstanceScan"] )

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have more than one element on page which has same xpath and same id/name , there are two fields on page with same locators i tried to enter value at desired location with below code

```
element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="testInstanceScan"]')).get(1).sendKeys('Vkumar');
```

but I faced error message:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but
>   there are only 1 elements that match locator By(xpath,
>   //*[@id="testInstanceScan"] )

if i used `element.all('#testInstanceScan').get(1).sendKeys('Vkumar');`

i faced error

> Failed: Invalid locator Stack: TypeError: Invalid locator

Tried with `element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).get(0).sendKeys('Vkumar');`
but its not the desired place for this value,.
values is entered in previous fields with this 0th intdex.

Comment: clearly says that `but there are only 1 elements` so the index should be 0 so you have ti try `.get(0).`

Comment: It's incorrect HTML syntax to have two elements with the same ID. If you do that, all the rules break down. You need to fix that problem, and then use something other than ID to identify your two elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Several elements with the same ID responding to one CSS ID selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a single element, that has a unique ID, you don't need to use `element.all()` but `element()`.

Your code should be

```
element(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).sendKeys('Vkumar');
```

Or even shorter:

```
$('#testInstanceScan').sendKeys('Vkumar');
```

Check also the API on [Protractor Homepage](http://protractortest.org/#/api)

To prove, that there is only one element you can try this:

```
element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).count().then(function(numberOfElems){
    console.log('For this ID I found '+numberOfElems+' elements.');
})
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply
My page has more than one element with same xpath/css even same id/name.
that's why i am using element.all get all elements

Comment: Your error message disagrees with you. According to your error message "there are only 1 elements that match locator By(xpath, //*[@id="testInstanceScan"] )". So for the example you posted you only have 1 unique match. Therefore `get(0)` would work, but `get(1)` won't, because there is no 2nd element for your locator.

Comment: Given your update of your question, I assume your locator is wrong. Can you post the HTML of the element you want to get? `<div id="somethingElse">element</div>` ... and you got invalid locator, because your `element.all()` syntax was wrong... it should be `element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan'))` or `$$('#testInstanceScan')`

Comment: Hi i corrected my syntax as per your suggestion.
As per your suggested code i have found the number of element on page 
Result is 2 and able to enter values with below mentioned code 

var size = element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).count();
       element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).count().then(function(numberOfElems){
            console.log('For testInstanceScan ID I found '+numberOfElems+' elements.');
        })

if(expect(size).toBeGreaterThan(1))
    element.all(by.css('#testInstanceScan')).get(1).sendKeys('Vkumar');