# Trying to attach a div to a fixed footer

Tags: css, footer

I'm trying a very basic site, so I apologize for the juveniles question but I've been stuck for 2 days and I've hit a wall.

The lower tabs ("bottom_ul") are to be on top of the footer and stay with the footer, regardless of the page size. When I work with the top tabs ("top_ul") they work perfectly. I've managed to get the tabs to the bottom, but I want them to move up and I can't figure out how to move them up, without them sticking in that new place (like, if I position them "just right" and then resize the page, they stay in place while the rest of the page moves around them if that makes any sense).

When I resize the page, I want the bottom_ul to stay with the footer, like the top_ul does with the header.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,300&family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap');
#mainheader {
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  word-spacing: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top_ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#header_links,
#footer_links {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
}

#header_links:hover,
#footer_links:hover {
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
}

#bottom_ul {
  position: fixed;
  /*margin-top: 530px;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  /*flex: 0 1 auto;
  top: 0;*/
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#footer_content {
  margin: 10px 150px 10px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="bottom_ul">
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Scores</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">History</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul id="footer_containter">
      <li id="footer_content">copyright info and such</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

HTML:
```

```
    <div>
        <ul id="bottom_ul">
            <li id="footer_links"><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li id="footer_links"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
            <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Scores</a></li>
            <li id="footer_links"><a href="">History</a></li>
            <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Content</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<footer class="footer">
        <nav>
            <ul id="footer_containter">
                <li id="footer_content"> Copyright</li>
                <li id="footer_content"> Mailing: 12344 Potato Ave. <br> Veggieville, USA 15227</li>
                <li id="footer_content">Social Media Links</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML as well, to create a [mre]

Comment: Gabrielle, HTML in comments is unreadable; please use the [edit] link below your question and add the code there, ideally as a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) :) Could you add the #bottom_ul to the beginning of the `<footer>`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for the correction. I've added it to the post proper. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: "but I want them to move up and I can't figure out how to move them up" I don't understand this part of your description.  When should they "move up"?

Comment: I suppose it's not that I want them to move "up," but I want them to stay with the footer. I always want them pinned directly above the footer. If I resize the page, they don't move at all. But the footer will adjust with the page size correctly.
Maybe they should be in the footer itself and I make another div within that for the tabs?

Comment: Using another `<div>` isn't necessary (that way lies [div-soup](https://www.hackterms.com/div%20soup)!) this is probably how I'd implement it: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ancuox4y/

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You cannot have more than one ID attribute of the same name.

Comment: With respect David Thomas, the jsfiddle you provided has no real relevance to his problem with no explaination and its way too complicated to understand. Your thinking about how it works is correct but someone that has clearly limited knowledge will be confused with the javascript code too like it is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to simply put your `#bottom_ul` inside the `#footer` div.

If you're not able to modify the HTML structure, you could position the ul the same way you do the footer, but with a different `bottom` value to leave room for the footer:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#header_links,
.footer_links {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
}

#header_links:hover,
.footer_links:hover {
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
}

#bottom_ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 4em;
}

#footer_content {
  margin: 10px 150px 10px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="bottom_ul">
    <li class="footer_links"><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li class="footer_links"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="footer_links"><a href="">Scores</a></li>
    <li class="footer_links"><a href="">History</a></li>
    <li class="footer_links"><a href="">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul id="footer_containter">
      <li id="footer_content">copyright info and such</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why placing the `bottom_ul` inside the footer wouldn't work for you?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,300&family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap');
#mainheader {
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  word-spacing: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top_ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#header_links,
#footer_links {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
}

#header_links:hover,
#footer_links:hover {
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
}

#footer_content {
  margin: 10px 150px 10px 100px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#bottom_ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul id="bottom_ul">
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Scores</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">History</a></li>
    <li id="footer_links"><a href="">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <ul id="footer_containter">
      <li id="footer_content">copyright info and such</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

**Side note:** Using `ID` for styling multiple elements in CSS is generally not recommended because an ID is meant to be unique within a page. I would recommend you use a class name to assign custom styling to your elements, rather than `ID` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/several-elements-with-the-same-id-responding-to-one-css-id-selector).

Comment: When I do that, the "tabs" that make up the list overlap with the footer, but I want it to sit on top of the footer

Comment: @Gabrielle comparing my code snippet to yours, it looks like the initial code is overlapping, and on mine it is sitting on top. Can you be more specific? Is the code snippet not what you are looking for, or is it not working when being translated to your site?

Comment: @Jacob It's not a recommendation. Multiple same-name IDs are invalid. Not allowed by the HTML standard.

Comment: @Jacob & @ Rob
When I attempted to apply it, for some reason it continues to show sitting within the footer (inside the bottom blue bar). But I'm also realizing that there are other flaws with my HTML/CSS other than just the footer. I apologize for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is wrap the bottom in one Div, which is essentially what Jacob suggests but I have tried to simplify your code in general because you have so much unnecessary code in the CSS styles. This example works for want you want I think but you can change and play with spacing and margins, etc. It is cleaned up so it is easy enough to understand.

You maybe confusing the way flex works and also CSS in general. I have included links for many examples and tutorials.

Also, use the inspect code in developer tools in your browser, you can play with the code and see results in the browser and what is doing what. Also have a look at bootstrap and it will make setting what the user sees depending on their device and screen size easy. Sorry if it is a lot to take in but it seems you have already invested a good bit already.

Also, I have not done your exact spacing and margins but its it easy enough to change now.

CSS basics and good for any starter -

```
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp
```

Flexbox basics -

```
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
```

BootStrap

```
https://getbootstrap.com/
```

Hope fully it works ok.

```css
#footer_content {
  padding-bottom : 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

#footer-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(39, 11, 85);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#bottom_ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
 font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-container">

  <ul id="bottom_ul">
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Scores</a></li>
    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
  
    <ul id="footer_content">
      <li>Copyright</li>
      <li>Mailing: 12344 Potato Ave</li>
      <li>Social Media Links</li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at it for me. I will try to work it out. At this time, I cannot use bootstrap just yet (not what they want me to us just yet), but I understand that I wasn't using the flexbox properly. Thank you for the resources and taking a look at my code.

Comment: It was not so much a Flex problem just how you ordered the  div layout, like I said you should of placed it all in 1 containing div.  I have updated the code so you can use it and if the solution is right for you, please click the tick for accepted answer and good luck moving forward